# How to display portion of next page in UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

I want to implement UIPageViewController in such a ways that some portion of next page will be visible so that user will come to know that there are pages available and he can scroll.
Is there any way to achieve this?

[image]

I want paging mechanism like above image.Is it possible using UIPageViewController?

Comment: Do you need only a UIView as one page or must it be a UIViewController? First solution ist very easy using an UIScrollViewController. Second solution is much more tricky using ChildViewControllers and subclassing UIView to change the hitTest: method etc.

Comment: Thanks   Claus Bönnhoff  for your help. I need UIViewController